# mysql and indexes with more than one column

Tags: mysql, database-indexes

How to use indexes with more than one column

The original index has an index on `block_id`, but is it necesarry when it's already in the unique index with two column?

**Indexes with more than one column**

(a,b,c)

- you can search for a, b and c
- you can search for a and b
- you can search for a
- you can **not** search for a and c

Does this apply to unique indexes too?

## table

```
id
block_id
account_id
name
```

## indexes origin

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
UNIQUE KEY `block_id` (`block_id`,`account_id`)
KEY `block_id` (`block_id`),
KEY `account_id` (`account_id`),
```

## indexes alternative

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
UNIQUE KEY `block_id` (`block_id`,`account_id`)
KEY `account_id` (`account_id`),
```

Answer (score 1):

The rules you describe above have to my knowledge always held whether an index is unique or not.  You might run explain on the query you have in mind and observe when the index is used and when it is not used under various circumstances.