# What is the benefit to having more than one column in a non-unique index?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321332/mysql-and-indexes-with-more-than-one-column) similar question about having more than one index, but the answer given is very short and does not give much detail.

I have two database tables.

```
INVENTORY
| pKey | colName1 | colName2 | ... | colName70 |

HISTORY
| id | pKey | fieldName | oldValue | newValue |
```

The history table is a record of changes on each item in the inventory.

When history table is queries, sometimes the pKey is used, other times a search can be performed searching for rows where fieldName = "colName4".

I have the history table indexed by pKey (non unique and by itself) and indexed by fieldName (non unique and by itself), but I was wondering if there would be a benefit to indexing it by pKey and fieldName together with a non-unique index?

What is the benefit to having more than one column in a non-unique index and how does it work?

Comment: I think the MySQL documentation does a good job of explaining multi-complex indexes:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff, this does not specify between unique and non-unique indexes. Do they work the same?

Comment: They basically work the same.

Comment: If "the history table is a record of changes" means it lets you reconstruct the sequence of values for a pKey & fieldName for arbitrary sequences then your design is inadequate. You need a column that orders rows with the same pKey & fieldname (which could be id, or a restriction on the sequence of values to be in a certain order, or an added ordinal or date column). Otherwise you don't know what the sequence of values was, just what pairs of old & new ever happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any set of columns that includes a set of unique columns is unique.

So an index on some unique columns plus others is just as unique. So it's not a case of "non-unique index". There is still a 1:1 correspondence with rows.

The benefits of such an index are the same as for any index on multiple columns. Eg sorted access, in-memory access, etc.

As Gordon Linoff commented: "[MySQL documentation does a good job of explaining multi-complex indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)" and "They basically work the same." (Indeed that section is on "Multiple-Column Indexes".)

In relational theory a "candidate key" (CK) (one of which can be chosen as primary key) is a unique set that doesn't contain a smaller unique set. That's what one uses in normalization. Any superset of a CK (including itself) is a "superkey". And a "foreign key" (FK) is formed by columns matching/referencing some CK. But in SQL`UNIQUE NOT NULL` declares a superkey, because it can contain a smaller set `UNIQUE NOT NULL`. And one of those can be written `PRIMARY KEY`, which is also just a superkey. And `FOREIGN KEY` actually declares a foreign superkey.

Comment: Reading your question and my answer now, do I really answer your question? It seems that I thought pKey was a candidate key of History but it seems clear to me now that you are saying that {pKey, fieldName} is not unique.